# Find the ciphering method 2

Tags: cipher, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence, no-computers

[Link to the entire series.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A85112%20title%3A%22Find%20the%20ciphering%20method%22)

The message:

> 3, 53, 48751, 9247757, 294914580539

The answer is a 13 letter word: **UNDERSTANDING**

Hint 1:

> One mathematical operation is 50% of the puzzle.

Comment: After a quick search, they're all primes. Surely not an accident(?)

Comment: @BenjaminWang - it's neither. Not an important detail, nor an accident. Them being primes doesn't matter.

Comment: One hint please

Comment: I try to sum each number   and after converting each digit into a letter now I have this : cjejcecihhbaf but if i try do anagram I don't find nothing that have sense :/

Comment: @IlCorsaroNero - You are not far from solving it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Encoding

Following [IlCorsaroNero's idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122094/find-the-ciphering-method-2#comment341396_122094) of adding all the numbers together, we instead try to multiply all the numbers in the message, to obtain the number `21140405181920011404091407`.
We notice that this is a 26 digit number, exactly twice the length of our 13 letter word. By splitting the number into groups of two digits, we get `21, 14, 04, 05, 18, 19, 20, 01, 14, 04, 09, 14, 07`.
Replacing each two digit group with its corresponding letter in the alphabet yields `UNDERSTANDING`.

### Decoding

To decode a message, we do the reverse of encoding. The only difference is what numbers we factorise the initial number into. Following an [observation made by Benjamin Wang](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122094/find-the-ciphering-method-2#comment340879_122094) that all the numbers are prime, we can guess that the initial number should be factorised into primes and then these primes organised into ascending order.

Comment: Your answer is correct for the most part :) However, numbers do not have to be primes, initial number can be broken up into non-prime factors (if possible). That is why numbers being primes is not important.

Comment: I see, I thought that your comment about it not being an accident might have been a part of the decoding process. Does that mean they only have to be in ascending order, or is that also optional, considering they all give the same decoded message?

Comment: The key part of this cipher is multiplication. The number containing letter numbers is factorized into primes or non-primes, which then have to be multiplied to get the initial number. Prime factorization simply was easier to code. Order of numbers does not matter since we need to multiply them.